# Copyright, privacy rights

Tags: copyright, extortion

I made the mistake of buying an essay online, due to having surgery and no time to write it. Now the website is trying to get more money from me threatening to call the university and the Board to show the paper and my name and the conversation we had because they claim I have to pay for copyright, not just the price for writing the essay. They say they did not know about this, as I asked why did they not tell me about this additional cost before, so I should know the essay is just for me to read, and not submit it to the University, as I stated clearly what I am going to be using it for. Please, could you help me clarify this? Thank you.

Comment: Jurisdiction?chars

Comment: What is the website?

Comment: The reaction to the extortion is the minor issue here - its the academic ethics issue which has the wider reach and has no jurisdictional or time limit.  If you threaten the extortionists with the police, they may retaliate.  If you pay up, they may come back in a years time with the same demands.  If everything goes ok and the extortionists go away, your paper may be flagged up by any number of other means at any point between now and the end of time, potentially destroying your academic standing and any career based on it.  Degrees may be rescinded, job offers removed, law suits filed...

Answer (score 7):

As Putvi says, you are being extorted and this is a criminal matter and thus a matter for the authorities in your jurisdiction.

However, you have a second problem entirely apart from that - you almost certainly broke academic ethical rules by submitting a piece of work that you did not write as your own (these things are pretty cut and dried in academic circles).  This will not go away.  Regardless of whether your extortionists are brought to justice, they can still release your details at any point in time and ruin your career, or it can come out in other ways.

Own up to this with your university as soon as possible, and see if you can make it right.  This will be hanging over you for the rest of your life, and can drop at any moment - these sorts of things have ruined people before.

Answer (score 0):

You are being extorted call the police.

You should not have given out your personal information when doing something that could get you in trouble.